# .Net Framework in Linux using wine

Tags: .net, testing, wine, linux-mint

How can i  install .Net Framework in Linux mint  using wine? I want to develop test framework using nunit and selenium in linux. As my machine is 64 bit, I am getting exception while installing. Please help me.

Comment: Any reason you can't use [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)? There are packages for Mint.

Comment: In Mono Develop, nunit is not recognised.

Comment: I have done it using Mono Develop by installing NUnit plugin.

Comment: Can you provide more detail? The question is too vague.

Comment: Link: [Setup a Test Project with NUnit and MonoDevelop](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34161/Setup-a-Test-Project-with-NUnit-and-MonoDevelop)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [mono develop](http://monodevelop.com/Download) from monoproject.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a link to the mono develop site or something?